# Cast WCF Event Handler Parameters to What Type?

Tags: wcf, events

In a .NET 4.0 WCF service, I have the Closed event hooked. The method/event looks like this right now:

```
void host_Closed( object sender , EventArgs e )
{
    Console.WriteLine("Host closed.");
}
```

But I would like to cast sender or e to something useful so I can do better logging than that. What Types are acceptable there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ICommunicationObject events don't give you much to go on. If you want rich error info to log, you'll have to implement IErrorHandler and install your error handler in your service's ChannelDispatcher (by means of behaviors).

Comment: Thanks. My question was poorly described, but you saw through that and gave me actually what I needed (to websearch for). Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint in the debugger. Look to see what the actual type of `sender` is. Use that.

As to `e`, I suspect it is really sending an `EventArgs` instance.

Comment: sender is most certainly the ServiceHost instance.

Comment: Hi, @Lars, of course it is. I wanted him to see for himself, learn the technique, and learn the pattern.